# Proving Dirichlet's Kernal is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Define for $n = 0,1,2,...$ the Dirichlet Kernal $D_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by:

$D_n(t) = \frac{\sin((n + 1/n)t)}{\sin(t/2)}$ for $ t \not = 2\pi m, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $D_n = 2n+1$ for $t = 2\pi m, m \in \mathbb{Z}$. I was asked to show that this is continuous by the definition of continuity. I am trying to now show it is continuous by using l'hospital's rule. Any help on this please, as I cannot see how to apply the theorem in this case.

Comment: All you need to prove is $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin((n + 1/n)t)}{\sin(t/2)} = 2n+1$. Yes, L'H works.